# Reading a .tif file in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, tiff

I am reading a .tif file to retrieve the header data in C#. but when I try to read the data I am getting following error.

```cs
Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
TiffBitmapDecoder tiffdecoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
BitmapSource firstframe = tiffdecoder.Frames[0];
```

compiler parser first line siccessfully but if I look it into the object I saw this error : ReadTimeout = 'imageStreamSource.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' and WriteTimeout = 'imageStreamSource.WriteTimeout ' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'.

and the TiffBitmapdecoder throwing the error: **The codec cannot use the type of stream provided.** Am I using wrong class fro decoding ? any better way to do read the header information and then parse the image for some symbols on it are very appreciated.